# Finding minimum difference between two cells over range?

Tags: excel

Given the values below...

```
  A        B       C       D       E     (F)    (G) is ABS()
Blake ... 292 ... 290 ... 291 ... 285
           0      -2      +1      -6             6

Alan  ... 262 ... 253 ... 252
           0      -9      -1                     9
```

...how would I find the minimum difference between pairs of cells (B:C, C:D, D:E, etc), with the goal to find the "most weight lost in one week?"

`-6` and `-9` are the answers I'm looking for.

*This is for an office weight loss challenge thingy .. and I'm not incredibly familiar with Excel. Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -6 and -9 are the answers I'm looking for.

Use this one in `G1`:

```
=MIN(IF(C1:E1<>"",C1:E1-B1:D1))
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula. Then drag formula down.

---

If you'd like to returns `ABS` of your min value, use:

```
=ABS(MIN(IF(C1:E1<>"",C1:E1-B1:D1)))
```

with array entry

Comment: Ahh, you're awesome, thank you :) I knew what I needed to do, just couldn't figure out the syntax. If you see this, can you answer really quickly what the difference between a normal formula and array formula is?

Comment: Hmm:) actually it's difficult to explain, but.. An array formula can perform multiple calculations and then return either a single result or multiple results. Array formulas act on two or more sets of values known as array arguments. [More info here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010228458.aspx). It better to see difference between normal vs. array formulas when using [Evaluate Formula tool](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-HP010066254.aspx)